# Location of .tex file differs rendering (modern cv)

Tags: moderncv

Im currently diving into modern cv.

I used latex many times, but i am far away to be very experienced with latex

I downloaded the package and modified the contents (only values).
I placed that file outside from example folder (in root of modern cv)
Apparently there are some differences in rendering, influenced by location, the tex file resides.

See this screenshots:

screen-1 (root of modern cv folder):
[image: root-folder]

screen-2 (in /examples folder):
[image: examples-folder]

What I basically want to achieve is to use "+" for cvitems (screen-1) and to use the proper symbols of for email, linked-in, github (screen-2).

How to achieve this ? Or better said, how to achieve this and being independent of the file location ?

Comment: I bet you are running once the old template of moderncv, and once the newer version installed wit TeX Live or MikTeX. You can find out the details by adding `\listfiles` to the very top of your main file and comparing the different lists in the log file.

Comment: I was acutally changing a few weeks before from `MikTex` to `texlive`. It was an old version (2013) and `tlmgr` didnt worked for me. Switching to latest version helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download a new package then you should put it in the tex document tree and run something like `mktexlsr` for it to apply globally.  Otherwise, the package will only `hit' where it is located.

Better yet, use the package update system that comes with the version of tex that you have (miktex, texlive, etc).  That will ensure that everything falls into place automatically.

Comment: Ty for your reply, `tlmgr` didnt worked for me in my case, but it turned out, that i had used an old `texlive` version. So i purged that old one, and reinstalled the latest. By that, nearly all packages were preinstalled, including moderncv. Works like a charm now